# How to use min in formula

Tags: ruby, eval

How to `min` inside the formula to evaluate using `eval()`.

`[5,6].min` works fine but it doesn't work inside the formula `eval([5,6].min*5)`.

Comment: ... why the heck are you using `eval`?

Comment: Eval needs a string to run

Comment: Such are the perils of a quick-draw checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using `#eval`. But why you need `#eval` ?

```
eval('[5,6].min * 5')
# => 25
```

Simply `[5,6].min * 5` will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `eval`.

`[5,6].min*5`.